# checkbox group multiple insert with MYSQL achieveable?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

how is it possible to output my rows into a checkbox group and insert them into a database at based on the ID of the items checked?

So user checks 1,2,3,4,5 and I insert the ID of 1,2,3,4,5 into myTable.

I've only ever dealt with 1 x $myVariable INSERTS so far..

Comment: could you clarify your question? And why would you insert 3 into table if a user haven't checked 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an extended insert syntax. Assuming your checkbox values are stored in a normalized table, you'd use something like

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (checkboxID) VALUES ($id1), ($id2), ($id3), etc...
```

which would produce a new record in `yourtable` for each value you specify. Note that you can insert sets of values in the same manner:

```
INSERT .... VALUES ($x, $y), ($a, $b), ($c, $d) etc...
```

You'd have to build up that list of values yourself, as the brackets around them are required for the extended insert to work. You can't simply do `INSERT .... implode($_POST['checkboxes']` type of thing.

Now, if you want to insert a comma-separated list of IDs into a single field/record in the DB, then I strongly suggest you don't. Normalize your database and create a sub-table for those values.

Comment: The ID's will be inserted into a linking table, that only holds ID's. It's basically a list of ID's belonging to a Foo. So they choose Foo, and select which values to add to Foo. The ID's of the values are stored in a linking table with the Foo ID inserted with them... So i'll want to Add Foo's ID for every value selected.

Answer (score 1):

Name your checkbox as an array and then check on submission if each index is checked or not.

For example:

```
<input type='checkbox' name=content[] value='1'>1
<input type='checkbox' name=content[] value='2'>2
<input type='checkbox' name=content[] value='3'>3
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['content'] as $record)
{
    // insert query
}
```

Comment: `$record` will be always set, there is no need to check with `isset()`.

Comment: Yes that's true. I am always prudent about checking conditions :p

Comment: But won't this insert 12345? I need separate rows

Comment: @SMacFadyen `foreach` is a loop, so for each checkbox that is checked you can execute query or you can format the query once inside the loop and execute it once after the loop?

Comment: Ah I get that point. Thanks for explaining. I just need to output the checkboxes out in a loop now.